# Alternating Words in Strings- Python

Tags: python, string, list, alternate

I have to create a program that asks the user for two strings and then 
generates a new string alternating one word from the first string 
and one word from the second string, where “word” is defined as above as anything between spaces or punctuation marks. When 
one string runs out of words just use the rest of the longer string. 
(For example ‘This. is. a, test’ and ‘My mom makes a mean pasta 
sauce’ will produce ‘This My is mom a makes test a mean pasta 
sauce’)

Any input would be appreciated I'm trying to learn how to program and what I have currently isn't working at all.

Comment: Well, you need to specify the language. String processing varies tremendously between different programming languages. But, in general terms, you need to first split each string according to your delimiting characters " ,.?!", and then loop through them simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs for Python's itertools module. The function itertools.izip_longest in particular (solves the exact problem you are posting).

From the docs:

itertools.izip_longest(*iterables[, fillvalue])
Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables. If the iterables are of uneven length, missing values are filled-in with fillvalue. Iteration continues until the longest iterable is exhausted.

If one of the iterables is potentially infinite, then the izip_longest() function should be wrapped with something that limits the number of calls (for example islice() or takewhile()). If not specified, fillvalue defaults to None.

Answer (score 0):

The `random` module is a great module which will help with this.

I use the `string` module to remove all the punctuation.

```
import random
import string
sentence_one = raw_input('Enter the first sentence! ').translate(None, string.punctuation)
sentence_two = raw_input('Enter the second sentence! ').translate(None, string.punctuation)
mylist1 = sentence_one.split()
mylist2 = sentence_two.split()
mylist3 = mylist1 + mylist2
random.shuffle(mylist3)
randomsentence = ' '.join(mylist3)
print randomsentence
```

When run:

```
Enter the first sentence! one, two, three
Enter the second sentence! four! five! six!
three two four six one five # Well it could be anything really, this is randomised.
```